# gulp watch not working when browsersync is added

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I try to get a simple workflow running where changes in the sass-file are immediately translated into css and displayed in the browser (using this tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/)
I looked through multiple answers to simliar questions here but couldn't find a solution.

This is my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');


gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/**/*.sass') // Gets all files ending with .scss in app/scss
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
    stream: true
  }))
});

var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'app'
    },
  })
})

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series(['browserSync'], ['sass']), function(){
  gulp.watch('app/**/*.sass', gulp.series(['sass']));
})
```

When I call `gulp sass` it works perfectly fine. Also, when I remove the browsersync and only use the following code the watching itself works:

```
gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch('app/scss/*.sass', gulp.series(['sass'])); 
})
```

There must be something wrong with the way the browsersyncing is (not) happening. Can someone help me out? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is not in gulp v4 syntax:

```
gulp.task('watch', gulp.series(['browserSync'], ['sass']), function(){
  gulp.watch('app/**/*.sass', gulp.series(['sass']));
})
```

Move the function into the `series` arguments.  So try this instead:

```
gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('browserSync', 'sass', function(){
  gulp.watch('app/**/*.sass', gulp.series('sass'));
}));
```

In this way `gulp.task()` takes 2 arguments instead of 3 - that is the gulp v4 way.  That article was written in v3 syntax unfortunately, with a few warnings to change the code for v4.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, it still won't watch the .sass file. In the console, it says "starting 'watch'..." and "starting 'browsersync'..." but it does not seem to start the task "sass". do you  have an idea what else could be wrong?

Comment: i found the error: I needed to change the browsersync-task to 
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
gulp.task('browserSync', function(done) {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'app'
    },
  })
  done();

})
I had tried out that part before but it didn't work because I didn't yet include the changes you suggestested!